# Do i need to use a plugin for third party api integration?

Tags: plugins, rest-api, api

I am new to WP and was wondering if i need a plugin for third party api integration. I want to retrieve data form the jira api and display it on my WP site. If i need a plugin, which do you recommend? Or should i create my own.

I did ask this question at stackoverflow but they didn't like me over there so i'll try my luck here.

Comment: Hi Thinsanta! Great name. It's probably not that they didn't like you, it's probably that you hadn't read some rules or guidelines and your post was simply outside of those. You can see some rules and guidelines for this Wordpress Development stackexchange here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour . You'll note that plugin recommendations are off topic here too so you may get some answers, or you may need to find a different venue, or ask a more specific question that is on-topic here.

Comment: Keep in mind that recommendations are offtopic here

Comment: Looks like this has already been addressed:  https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-discussions/WordPress-Plugin-to-integrate-Jira-on-a-website/td-p/460585

All I did was google 'JIRA API WordPress', it was the first result.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. Very helpful and i'll look into the url about guidlines and url for jira!

Answer (score 0):

You can do both:

- If a plugin exists for JIRA integration or accessing data from JIRA, and it does what you need, then yes you can use it
- If it does not, or you prefer to build your own, that too is an option

However, I cannot recommend a particular plugin, and you will need to consult JIRA API documentation for details on how to build your own.

You can use the `WP_HTTP` APIs to speak to the JIRA API, though you will need to ask in JIRA developer communities for how to speak with those APIs to retrieve the data you desire.

Once you have the data, you can store it and display it on the frontend using various options:

- shortcodes
- blocks
- page templates
- posts created using the data that was retrieved

Comment: Thank you for the information and taking your time! I will look further into what you said. It helped me understand wp a bit more.